# Is session maintained when user presses back/forward buttons in browser?

Tags: session, browser, back, forward

I have a javascript popup that alerts users when their session is about to expire.

On the master page > page load -  if the user is logged in I do registerClientStartupScript and call setTimeout(showPopup, time). So that this is in effect on all pages.

My question is.. if session timeout is set to 20 minutes for example, and my popup is set show at 19 minutes.. when the user clicks "back" or "forward" in their browser window - does the session get refreshed and the 20 minutes restarts? or does it continue counting up from where it was when you clicked back/foward?

If the latter, is there a way I can refresh session on back/forward?

Hopefully this makes sense, I appreciate any help!

Comment: What server are you using to serve the javascript from? Who is tracking the session, a server or the client app?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions as I'm fairly inexperienced here (sorry).. I'm using session in ASP.NET with timeout set in web.config. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. That is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I have no much nore information about javascript but other web farameworks like jsf php etc the session starts when user opened the browser and session  terminateted when  user closed the browser and I think generally session scobe  is not depend on programming languages